# Edit button link bug when logged off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I am not sure even how I've done this, but I think its like this:

I had two or three tabs opened, so I got logged out. But I've forgot that, and on the other tab, I've made an edit (removed tag which is not related to the question). Next what was happened is that I got message which says:

"Thanks for your edit, it will be reviewed ..."  Because, I have more than 2k rep, I logged, and approved my own edit :) Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32085903/3402095)

It says edit proposed by anonymous user (which is me :) and approved by me... I think this is a bug ;) Because we shouldn't have the ability to apply edits when logged out.

Comment: And downvote is for ?

Comment: I disagree it's a bug, im explaining in an answer now.

Comment: Anyways, I don't understand downvote. I just wanted to report unexpected behaviour in order to help in improving the site.

Comment: I just said, I down voted because I don't think it's a bug... I'm also not quite sure what you mean tbh - should anon users not be able to suggest edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because we shouldn't have the ability to apply edits when logged out

No, that's by design... Anonymous users can and do suggest edits. They do have to be reviewed, buy two people - as the banner says - *"Thanks for your edit, it will be reviewed"*.

If you mean you shouldn't be able to approve edits when logged out, you can't.

As the review says, it was *"proposed 18 mins ago by an anonymous user"* - which in this case was you.

But the system doesn't know that. The system thinks - *"Oh a suggested edit. Let's get it reviewed. Oh, it's approved, yay."*

> and approved by me

also note that it was approved by someone else. This shows that there is nothing different from me (at 450 rep) proposing an edit to you when logged out. Still needs 2 reviewers to approve it.

Comment: Okay, to clarify, any user, even with 0 rep can suggest edit ?

Comment: Well no one has 0 rep. You are either no signed up, or have 1 rep. Anyone can suggest an edit.

Comment: Thanks... That explains this behaviour . I thought that I shouldn't be able to suggest an edit if I am logged off.